# Excel 2013 INDEX/MATCH vs. SUMIFS efficiency for looking up values with multiple parameters

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, speed

Often times I find that I need to look up a value from a table using multiple parameters.  For example, in [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktc67.png) I have two columns containing two levels of categories (e.g. the category "Food" with subcategories "Groceries", "Restaurants", etc.).

If I want to do something like calculate the % of my spending on food that went to restaurants, I would need to pull out the value for Food/Groceries and divide it by the total of all my food records.  I could retrieve the value for this parameter in two ways:

- Generate a ["key"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMloL.png) column that is the concatenation of the two categories, then do and INDEX/MATCH to find the appropriate value

  - In the "key" example: INDEX($E$3:$E$9,MATCH("FoodRestaurants",$B$3:$B$9,0)))
- Use SUMIFS() to sum all the values with both the "Food" and "Groceries" labels in each of the respective columns

  - In the original table: SUMIFS($D$3:$D$9,$B$3:$B$9,"Food",$C$3:$C$9,"Restaurants")

From a usability perspective, I would lean towards the latter of these two as it is easier to build and easier to read later on.  However, my concern is that for very large workbooks it could become much less efficient than the INDEX/MATCH approach.  Does anyone have any idea of the relative efficiency of these two operations?  Bonus points if there's another method better than either.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a different method you can use sumproduct like the following:

`=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B9="Food")*(C3:C9="Groceries")*D3:D9)`
`Where B3:B9="Food" will give 1 if True`
`Also C3:C9="Groceries" will give 1 if True`

And Sumproduct will add the products 1*1*values in 2015

To compare Index/Match vs Sumifs click [Here](http://professor-excel.com/when-to-use-vlookup-sumifs-or-indexmatch-in-excel/)